# how to print top ten most repeated words from the container c++

Tags: c++, stl, multimap

I need to print out the first 10 most repeated words from the container. My program is printing all the repeated words and when i put`count=10` it is printing first 10 repeated words. But, I need to print first 10 most repeated words. What code do I need to use to get most repeated first 10 words.

Required Output:

```
            Word     Count
             the      19
               a      14
              of      11
      artificial      11
            that      10
              to       7
          signal       7
             and       7
              in       6
            they       5
```

My code:

```
// Displays 10 most frequent words in KnownWords
void WordStats::DisplayMostFreqKnownWords(){
    int count;
    multimap<int,string > displayFreqWords; 
    multimap<int,string >::reverse_iterator rit = displayFreqWords.rbegin();        
    for (Paragraph = KnownWords.begin();  Paragraph != KnownWords.end(); 
    ++Paragraph)
    { 
        string word = (*Paragraph).first;
        int cnt = (*Paragraph).second.size();
        displayFreqWords.insert(pair<int,string>(cnt,word)); 
    }
      cout <<"           Word      Count\n";
      for(;rit!=displayFreqWords.rend(); count<=10, ++rit ,  ++count){  
      string word = (*rit).second;
      int cnt = (*rit).first;
      cout << setw(15) << word << setw(10) << cnt << endl;

    }
}
```

My output:

```
       Word     Count
      about         1
  aggregate         1
    another         1
        any         2
   approach         2
  attention         3
    biology         3
      board         4
     common         5
 constitute         5
```

Comment: Reverse iterators seem to be your answer. See [std::multimap::rbegin](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap/rbegin) and [std::multimap::rend](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap/rend)

Comment: I have used reverse iterator with count<=10 but compiler is ignoring "count". Please check coding , I have just added reverse_iterator into my program

Comment: Check your `for` loop. `for` loop has 3 parts, separated with semicolons. First part is initilialization, which is empty in your loop. Second part is condition, which is `rit!=displayFreqWords.rend()`, third part is loop control, which is in your loop `count<=10, ++rit ,  ++count`. See the problem?

Comment: It seems what you want to do is create a list of the top 10 most frequent words without using sorting.  Here is generally what I would do.  First use string operations to find the frequency of the word for all words in the paragraph(s) string.  If the word is not unique then do not do this search and move on to next word.
Next create a second list of the top 10 words.  Do loop for this list like this: while (word frequency is not greater than or equal list item && list is not at end) {if word is greater than equal to a word in list-bump that word from top ten list.}  hope this helps.